# How to you store data for each discord user in the discord server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to store the amount of money each player has, but I can't figure out how to have a custom variable for each discord user in the server. Any kind of help would be useful, thank you.

Comment: You know some code would be nice considering we can't help you without you trying to even solve the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Required Dependencies:** [sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite)

Well considering that this question is very general, I'll give a fairly **general answer**. Knowing that you're using **discord.js** ...

One way you can complete your goal, is by creating an `sqlite` database. *Note: this does not involve variables.* To do this, you will have to require `sqlite` as a dependency:

`const sql = require("sqlite");`

Once completed this, you can create the file, the database will be in:

`sql.open("./database.sqlite")`

After which you will set up the table for the users:

```js
sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userData (userId TEXT, money INTEGER)").then(() => {
    sql.run("INSERT INTO userData (userId, money) VALUES (?, ?)", [<user id object here>, 0]);
});
```

That would create a database you can use to store information about each user in your guild.

After which to update their balance follow this format (example):

```js
sql.get(`SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userId = ${msg.author.id}`).then(row => { //the row is the user's data
    if(!row) { //if the user is not in the database
      sql.run("INSERT INTO userData (userId, money) VALUES (?, ?)", [`${guildId}`, <user id object here>, 0]); //let's just insert them
      msg.channel.send("Registered.")
    } else { //if the user is in the database
      sql.run(`UPDATE userData SET money = ${row.money + 100} WHERE guild = ${msg.guild.id}`)
    }
});
```

If there are issues in the code provided or errors, feel free to comment or contact me :)

Comment: I would prefer Objects/Dictionaries because it's much more simple, but this also works. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to create database.sqlite, it makes it a text file. What do I need to download for it to register as a sqlite file?

Answer (score 2):

Objects/Dictionaries are perfect for this exact situation. You can create an object and create entries for each user using their userId.

```
var bankBalances = {};
bankBalances[pruina.id] = 5;
bankBalances[ekw.id] = 3;
```

though of course without knowing the library you're using, I can only give you pseudocode.

Comment: I'm using the discord.js library.